# Sorting only a single value in an array

Tags: python, sorting

Given an array, say `array = [3,5,-1,4,2,-1,5,0,-1]`, I want to sort it such that everything stays in the same place, except the -1's which will move to the end, so:

```
>>> function(array) 
[3,5,4,2,5,0,-1,-1,-1]
```

This could also be generalised to any number, however, I'm using -1 as a key value and need them to all be at the end of the array for some later processing.

I've tried playing with the sort() and sorted() inbuilt functions in python however neither of these seemed to be able to do what I needed.

Comment: you should go with map or filter instead

Comment: `print([i for i in array if i != -1] + [i for i in array if i == -1])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda function in your call to `sort`.  Here we sort the values by returning a 0 if the value is anything other than -1, otherwise 1.  This will push all of the -1 values to the right.

```
array.sort(key=lambda x: x==-1)
array
# returns
[3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: I like the "This will push all of the -1 values to the right" explanation

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
array = [3,5,-1,4,2,-1,5,0,-1]
num = -1
print([i for i in array if i != num] + [i for i in array if i == num])
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `sort` is stable, so you can just move some items around, leaving the others untouched

```
lst = [3,5,-1,4,2,-1,5,0,-1]

print(sorted(lst,key = lambda x : x == -1))
```

result: `[3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1]`

with this key, all items which are equal to `-1` yield `True` for the sort key, making them rise to the end of the list. Others are left where they are relatively to each other (because sort key yields the same `False` value for all of them).